# Problems with object respository after moving Delphi6 from XP to Windows7 64

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

On moving to windows7 I could not get Delphi6 to install. I found the solution to be not installing under Program Files (I installed in c:\Delphi). My problem is that now when I try to add a new item to my project (a dialog for instance) I get a message saying that the files cannot be found. I think it may be something to do with registry entries for Objrepos but I am not confident enough to go editing the registry.

Comment: You can easily install under Program Files. My Delphi 6 lives there. Just put a permissive ACL on the Delphi6 folder under program file \ borland

Comment: Delphi also works fine installed outside the Program Files folder. I have all my copies of older Delphi installed under *C:\Delphi*, and all my newer versions installed under *C:\RAD Studio*, and they all work fine (including the Object Repository items).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this sounds like a broken installation.

The Delphi installer in older version could be sensitive to certain thing.  For example, installing update, components or IDE add-ons before having first started the IDE (the registry could become messed up), or attempting a re-install over the top of a previously failed install (previous, invalid registry settings not properly over-written).

Rather than attempting to fix whatever installation issues have been caused, it may be simpler to simply eliminate these possible causes by doing a **complete** uninstall of the affected version, and re-install from scratch.

Whether you choose to install under Program Files with permissions changes, or under a separate folder, outside of Program Files (a personal preference - I myself favour the latter), *be sure to start (and shutdown) the IDE at least once immediately upon completing the initial installation*, to ensure initial registry settings are intact, **before** installing any updates, additional components or add-ons (such as GExperts etc).

Comment: Thanks Deltics - that solved the problem on my home machine where I had previously tried to do the default install and obviously the registry entries had not been set correctly. I will now ask the IT guys at work to do the same on my machine here although I am surprised it happened here as I asked them to install outside Program Files - perhaps they also tried the default installation first. Merry Christmas